# New to AI, generating “feedback data” from given user prestations?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

First I will clarify the context, I have to learn new technologies for my bachelor thesis. I am making a mobile application similar to Flappy Bird, except it's voice controlled. The idea is to have this app as a practice tool for people with voice problems (monotony). The bird flies upwards when the user makes a high pitch, and downwards when it's a low pitch.

The app part is pretty much complete. But my project also consists of a website where the vocal coach can follow his user's progress. I am saving all the user's game history in a database. More specifically, every time the bird passes through a pipe opening, I save the pitch values that he correctly produced. I also save the pitch value that made him lose the game, along with the pitch value that he was supposed to produce to not lose.

Having all these data in my database, this is where I'd like to add AI as a new technology for my project. I thought of a nice feature where it would calculate the user's strong and weak points. For example it would say that a user is strong at high pitches, but is not good at low pitches. But since I don't know anything about AI, I'm not sure to what extent this is possible and have no idea where to start.

I would really appreciate if someone could share their knowledge with me by pointing me to existing libraries/frameworks! I'd most preferably include the AI code inside my API that is directly connected to my database, so I can directly return the calculated data to my website. My API is a SpringBoot app, so I guess I would need Java AI libraries?